# Sentry error - IndexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, sentry

I am getting this error from **Sentry** repetitively in ios - safari 14.0 in react project.

There is no code trace and no other information than this but it repeats in almost every URL.

I have already searched for the options everywhere. I have tried debugging but I can't replicate it, and so I can't resolve it.

Does anyone know what does this error means? Or how can I add debug information in Sentry?

I have been looking for the solution for a while and couldn't get it. I know it's a bit lack of information to provide but that's why I am asking this. if someone can tell me how to deal with sentry errors if you don't know why it is repeating so often, it will be really helpful.

Comment: To add: I am not using canvas so there is nothing related to that.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue. I hope we do get more information out of this to determine the severity of the issue. If this is considered low severity and a rare edge case, it may be worth adding to the `ignoreErrors` Sentry option.

Comment: FWIW I'm running into the same thing in an Ember project. Our stacktrace seems to indicate it always happens when the user clicks a button.

Comment: @PeterBrown Same thing. It says it happens when the user clicks on a button. 

I do think there is something triggering it as it started before few days and still occurring. Maybe something with an event object on the button click on safari and edge. Still looking into it.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Does the user agent string for the events include "edgios" by chance? I think these issues are happening on Edge for iOS but Sentry is tagging them as mobile safari.

Comment: @Alex
Yes it is. I will test it today to know if it's replicating or not.

Comment: Yep, I was able to reproduce it by spamming button taps, especially submit buttons. What's weird is once it starts happening, it happens more often.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue still exists.
Faced this in Safari when Draft.js is updating the editor state.
The error which I see: IndexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range.

For me, playing around with `Paragraph Direction`context menus items after right-clicking on the Editor selection reproduced the error.

My Solution/hack:
Add it to any JS file executing before the Editor file.

```
const nativeSelectionExtend = Selection.prototype.extend;

  Selection.prototype.extend = function (...args) {
    try {
      return nativeSelectionExtend.apply(this, args);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Selection error.', error);
    }
  };
```

It works properly for me. Maybe will be useful for somebody as well.

Thanks to https://github.com/shpakkdv